# What does Core Motion CMErrorDomain error code 107 mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I use CMPedometer pedometer I get the error:

> Error Code=107 Domain=CMErrorDomain "(null)"
> Error Domain=CMErrorDomain Code=107 "(null)"

What does this error mean?

```
- (IBAction) startRun:(id)sender
    if(![CMPedometer isStepCountingAvailable]) {
        return
    }
    
    [self.pedometer startPedometerUpdatesFromDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 2] withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *_Nullable pedometerData, NSError* _Nullable error) {
        if(error ){
            NSLog(@"%@", error) ;
        }
        NSLog(@"steps:", pedometerData.numberOfSteps);
   }]:
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

You likely moved on by now but for others, this is very likely a date issue.

My case was using QueryPedometerData() and misunderstanding FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(). I thought it meant subtracting a number of seconds from Now but where its actually the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across with this problem. In my case, the error was caused by the fact that the start date and the end date I provided to the CMPedometer were the same (for example, start date - 12:59:59 and the end date - 12:59:59). As I set the end date manually, inclusion of nanoseconds in the end date solved the problem.